# Ssh use private key over 2 servers

Tags: ssh, session

Machine1 has private and public pair.
Machine2 and machine3 have public key.

I go to machine2 from machine1 over ssh and then I want to go to machine3 from machine2.
It's like that machine1--ssh-->machine2--ssh-->machine3
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Lets clarify this: the user you are establishing these connections as has a public/private key pair. In ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on machine2 and machine3 there is a copy of the connecting users public key?

If this is the case then on machine1 you should be running an [ssh-agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) to cache the credentials for your key. Here's what it looks like when I set up an ssh agent and cache my key:

```
<tbielawa>@(expressomaker)[~] 04:15:33
$ eval `ssh-agent`
Agent pid 21725
<tbielawa>@(expressomaker)[~] 04:15:20
$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /Users/tbielawa/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /Users/tbielawa/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/tbielawa/.ssh/id_rsa)
<tbielawa>@(expressomaker)[~] 04:15:31
$ ssh-add -l
2048 5f:e0:9b:92:e4:80:7e:5e:c8:29:00:29:ae:ca:bd:58 /Users/tbielawa/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

(You only need to run eval `ssh-agent` if one isn't running already)

Then when I make SSH connections I run the ssh command with the `ForwardAgent` option like this:

```
<tbielawa>@(expressomaker)[~] 04:17:58
$ ssh fridge -o "ForwardAgent yes"
Last login: Wed Nov  3 14:32:28 2010 from expressomaker
```

Except I don't do that all the time, my ~/.ssh/config file is configured to forward my agent automatically:

```
<tbielawa>@(fridge)[~] 04:18:03
$ cat .ssh/config
Host *
     ForwardAgent yes
```

If you run your ssh commands like this then your agent will be with you on `server`. You can then ssh to server3 using your public/private key combination.

Comment: A shorter form of -o "ForwardAgent yes" is simply to use -A.

Comment: @andol, I'm surprised I forgot to mention that. Nice addition! I guess I was thinking about the concept of agent forwarding in general.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh-agent` on machine1 and agent forwarding.  There is a [great guide](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html) from Steve Friedl which illustrates this in detail.

You might want to check out [keychain](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/keychain-guide.xml), too.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to login from one machine to another without a password, you need to use `ssh-keygen` tool to generate the key pair and then copy it to the destination machine.

The way to do it to create the key pair and then copy the public key to each server you want to have access. The file should be copied to `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Of course, you have to replace `/home/user` with the real user home directory.

Here are required the steps:

1- Create key pair on machine1.

2- Copy the generated public key to machine2.

3- Create another key pair on machine2.

4- Copy the generated public key to machine3.

Comment: this isn't necessary, you can use ssh agent forwarding as mentioned in other answers.